# Crawling Google map reviews hangs after 1040 reviews have loaded

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler

I'm using selenium crawling reviews of a place in google map with python. I used the script below to crawl the place that have over 4000 reviews.

```py
def getAllComments():  
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/button[2]').click()

    print('Updating pages...')
    batch_size = 5
    prev_len = 0
    
    while True:
        scrollable_ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#QA0Szd > div > div > div.w6VYqd > div.bJzME.tTVLSc > div > div.e07Vkf.kA9KIf > div > div > div.m6QErb.DxyBCb.kA9KIf.dS8AEf')
            
        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight', scrollable_ele)
            
        WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
f'#QA0Szd > div > div > div.w6VYqd > div.bJzME.tTVLSc > div > div.e07Vkf.kA9KIf > div > div > div.m6QErb.DxyBCb.kA9KIf.dS8AEf > div:nth-child(9) > div:nth-child({(prev_len + batch_size) * 3 -2})')))
            
        new_len = len(driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#QA0Szd > div > div > div.w6VYqd > div.bJzME.tTVLSc > div > div.e07Vkf.kA9KIf > div > div > div.m6QErb.DxyBCb.kA9KIf.dS8AEf > div:nth-child(9) > div.jftiEf.fontBodyMedium'))
        print('new_len: ', new_len)
        if new_len == prev_len:
            break
        prev_len = new_len
    print('Downloading comments...')
    ...
```

And the output of this code is always hang after getting 1040 reviews, and timeout after 30 seconds.

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keHII.png)

Does Google intentionally set the limit of loading reviews? Or there's some problem in my code? Can somebody help me to solve the problem? Please let me know if you have encountered the same issue.

#### Version

Python:3.9.0
Selenium:4.16.0
ChromeDriver:120

I've tried setting the Wait time to 1000 seconds, and change driver to Edge driver but it hangs either.

change

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ...
```

to

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ...
```